# Akward pose in Object Mode

Tags: armature

[image]

In Object Mode, my model looks strange and scary:

[image]

When I switch to Edit Mode, it appears normal:

[image]

Why is that so? Why does my model appear so scary and strange in Object Mode?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset the transform of your bones in Pose mode.

To do this, select the rig and enter pose mode. You should see it when clicking on "Object Mode" in the top left of the screenshot:

[image]

After entering Pose Mode, make sure all bones are selected by hitting A.

Then, go to Pose -> Clear Transform -> All

[image]

After clearing the transform on the bones, they will appear in the same way as they did in Edit mode.

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you tell me why the pose transform was so strange? A Blender bug perhaps?

Comment: @tmighty I really don't have a specific answer as to why. If you imported it, then in my experience importing from a different blender version can cause strange artifacts such as this. But, that is purely speculation for your specific issue.