# Pose Mode - Clear Transform - All still creates jumbled skeleton

Tags: blenderkit

Using tutorial to give character a bone in its body:
***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBYb1YmaOMY***

Following the guide:
***[Akward pose in Object Mode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186345/akward-pose-in-object-mode#)***
*(Which explains for to clear the transform very well.)*

When I am following this guide, **I get a Random Generated collection of bones being jumbled**.
What am I doing wrong as I have followed the guide but it does not revert to the edit mode state in Pose?

See screenshot here.
[image: Before Clear Transform Screenshot]

[image: After Clear Transform Screenshot]

Comment: EDIT - This is fixed if I remove my Inverse Kinematics, but i need them to move my character for the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following this tutorial below fixed my problem -
***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-2v_CKmVE8***

its a double loop, and to fix it, I had to create a duplicate of the hand.